# Unable to read params from request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, object, request

My Angular :

```
$http.get('/api/orders', {
        params: {
            userId:userId,
            token:token
        }
     })
     .success(function (data,status) {

     });
```

My Node :

```
  router.route('/')
        //GET all Orders
        .get(function(req, res, next) 
            {
           console.log(req);
          });
```

My Result :

```
.......
.
.
params:{},
query :{token:'mytoken',userId:'myUserId'}
.
.
......
```

Why my `params` is blank and `query` is filled with parameters.I want my data in `params`.Where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting params object, to `$http.get` method in agular you are simply adding data to query string. As written [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get):

```
params – {Object.<string|Object>} – Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as GET parameters.
```

So, it`s logic for them to appear in req.query object on server side. In order to get this data in req.param object, you have to map it in the route. Change route to:

```
app.get('/api/orders/:userId/:token', ...);
```

And angular request to:

```
$http.get('/api/orders/' + userId + '/' + token })
     .success(function (data,status) {

     });
```